# What does it mean to dynamic_cast<T>(event)?

Tags: c++, events, dynamic-cast

`event` is a highlighted keyword in MSVC++ Express 2008, and the following code is used in a framework:

```
else if (dynamic_cast<simulation::AnimateEndEvent*>(event))
{ ... }
```

What does it mean to `dynamic_cast` a keyword rather than a variable/object?

Comment: Event is not a keyword, its an object/variable.

Comment: `event` is a keyword only in C++/CLI (.net stuff), not plain-old c++. Unfortunately you can't tell Visual Studio to stop coloring it as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context event is a variable and not a keyword, even if the syntax highlighter can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, event is a variable. I assume you are compiling native C++, but event is also a [keyword in managed C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I imagine that the visual studio IDE is failing to distinguish between the two, but the compiler will get it right for you - even if intellisense/syntax highlighting does not.

Answer (score 0):

Event is not a keyword, its an object/variable.

Visual studio does all kinds of syntax highlighting for various kinds of objects, but keep in mind this is not 100% reliable, and frequently misidentifies pieces of code.